# Sample limit for each hour

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I query from each `HOUR` in my query? I want to sample 5 records in each `HOUR` but I am not sure how to do so. I know I can do it manually by hardcoding hour, but I want to do it with one query. The output would be something like

```
hour | location
00      SF
00      DC
00      VW
01      SF
01      HI
01      KK
02      JP
02      RU
02      CN
...    ...
...    ...
23      JK
23      ON
23      CN
```

This is what I have so far:

```
select hour, location
from db.table where
     hour in ('00', '01', '02','03', '04','05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16','17', '18', '19','20', '21', '22','23') 
order by hour
limit 3;
```

Comment: FOr this kind of questions, please include the table definition in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year, month, day, hour order by random()) as seqnum
      from db.table t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5;
```

I'm not sure what the `year`, `month`, and `day` columns have to do with your question.  They are not part of the sample data.  If you want only one day, then use a `where` clause as you have in your query.